# OpenIMAJ not able to access video file

Tags: java, ffmpeg, xuggler, xuggle, openimaj

I am using OpenIMAJ to draw facial keypoints on a video but it is stuck at the first step itself.
Here is the code I am trying to run::

```
Video<MBFImage> video;
    video = new XuggleVideo("file://E:/AV/out2.flv");//XuggleVideo("file:"+fileName);
    VideoDisplay<MBFImage> display = VideoDisplay.createVideoDisplay(video);
    display.addVideoListener(
             new VideoDisplayListener<MBFImage>() {
                    public void beforeUpdate( MBFImage frame ) {

                        FaceDetector<DetectedFace,FImage> fd = new HaarCascadeDetector(40);
                        List<DetectedFace> faces = fd.detectFaces( Transforms.calculateIntensity(frame));

                        for( DetectedFace face : faces ) {
                            frame.drawShape(face.getBounds(), RGBColour.RED);
                        }
                    }

                    public void afterUpdate( VideoDisplay<MBFImage> display ) {
                    }
      });
```

When I run this It prints

> file:///E:/AV/out2.flv URL file:///E:/AV/out2.flv could not be opened
>   by ffmpeg. Trying to open a stream to the URL instead. 11:14:12.505
>   [Finalizer] DEBUG com.xuggle.xuggler - Closing dangling Container
>   (../../../../../../../csrc/com/xuggle/xuggler/Container.cpp:146)

on the screen and then just dies out. result is same if I use video = new XuggleVideo(new File("E:/AV/out2.flv"));

Also if I keep file in the project and then do video = new XuggleVideo(new File("out2.flv")); I get same result.

I am able to access the file if I put the link in the browser. What is going wrong?

Update: I get just this

> out2.flv 12:03:06.485 [Finalizer] DEBUG com.xuggle.xuggler - Closing
>   dangling Container
>   (../../../../../../../csrc/com/xuggle/xuggler/Container.cpp:146)

If I use `video = new XuggleVideo("out2.flv");`

Comment: Is this still a problem? I think it might have been fixed by the changes made for OP-30 (http://jira.openimaj.org/browse/OP-30).

Answer (score 0):

Remove "File" and give your path only as "E:/AV/out2.flv". It will work.